# Appending child to dom adds a redundant namespace prefix to child

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

I am trying to append an XML fragment into a base document in php. For instance, the base document could be:

```xml
<A></A>
```

And the fragment is:

```xml
<B>
  <C xmlns="http://foo"/>
</B>
```

I expect the result to be:

```xml
<A>
  <B>
    <C xmlns="http://foo"/>
  </B>
</A>
```

I attempted to do this in 2 different ways:

```php
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML("<A></A>");
$childDom = new \DOMDocument();
$childDom->loadXML("<B><C xmlns=\"http://foo\"></C></B>");
$childNode = $dom->importNode($childDom->firstChild, true);
$dom->firstChild->appendChild($childNode);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

```php
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML("<A></A>");
$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML("<B><C xmlns=\"https://foo\"></C></B>");
$dom->firstChild->appendChild($fragment->firstChild);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Both of these produce the following result:

```xml
<A>
  <B xmlns:default="http://foo">
    <default:C xmlns="http://foo"/>
  </B>
</A>
```

Is there a way in php to obtain the expected result without the redundant `xmlns:default` attribute and the added `default` prefix?

Comment: `$dom->loadXML("<A xmlns=\"http://foo\"></A>");` prevents the default stuff. but now you have declaration also in top level element.  Can that be an workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$destination = $xpath->query('//A');

$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('
  <B>
    <C xmlns="http://foo"/>
  </B>
');

$destination[0]->appendChild($fragment);
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output should be your expected output.

Comment: It seems like yours does solve it, but in a roundabout way. The real reason it works is because there's whitespace before the <B> tag in the fragment. Doing `$fragment->appendXML('<B><C xmlns="http://foo"/></B>')` does not work, but doing `$fragment->appendXML('    <B><C xmlns="http://foo"/></B>')` works. Very strange. This whitespace of couse has semantics, so removing it after doing `appendChild` is a possibility.

Comment: @RamiroBalado Yes, there seems to be some kind of [long standing problem](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67948).